# List to txt file getting insanely large, I mean huge

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, large-files

thank you for your help in advance.

I have written a code to gather data on some institutions. From the main website an id is provided, and then I have the use that id, to find a second id that I need from a different source. To save time when institutions are repeated (I can have the same institutions in different years for example, so even though some data will be different, the second id won't) I am storing the pairs of ids within two arrays, with the same index, so if I have the "indexOf" one, I have the other wihtout having to go every time to get the data from the source for that institution.

This works great so far, however the problem is when I try to store this pairs. each string(id) is alphanumeric that can contain spaces but never exceeds 20 characters.

I try to save the list after some iterations to save the job before continuing the next day, so I can start with a dictionary already. The data is put into a text file in the following way, each line contains a pair:

id1;id2

The problem is that this txt file gets huge. I mean, with 16 000 lines, it's already above 300MB, and when it got above 60 000 it was already above 22GB of size.

There is obviously a problem as I have had files with more text taking far less space. I write the file in the following way:

```
List<String> aux = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0 ; i < nipcs.size() ; i++ ){

      aux.add(id1.get(i) + ";" + id2.get(i));

}

Files.write(file.toPath() , aux , StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I want to know if these file sizes are normal, or if there is another better method to do so. Basically I do not care if the txt file is "human-readable", just to be able to load its content into the id1 and id2 array the next day.

Thank you again!

Edit:

Here it is a sample of the txt file written, random 6 lines, copy-paste. I know I should expect to have around 120 000 lines max when all the institutions are registered.

```
ESA58357021;645090
507755383;346686
510216099;632378
207781818;840321
513268006;840323
502106344;54991
```

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question: no, these aren't normal. If the IDs are truly only 20 alphanumeric characters, then with your encoding, one line should take around 42-43 bytes: 20 for one ID, 20 for the other, 1 for the semi-colon, and 1 or 2 for the newline depending on line endings. Use the debugging feature of your favorite IDE to put a breakpoint in your `for` loop, or even better, break up your code and write unit tests to make sure chunks of your code do what you expect them to do.

Comment: Rather than loading all of the `String`(s) into a `List` and then writing the `List`, it would be more efficient to write the `String`(s) to the file directly. That doesn't have anything to do with why your file is so large.

Comment: With this much information you might want to look into using a database, like SQLite or MYSQL.

Comment: You're not telling us what the data looks like in your files, I really don't know how you hope we can help you. 22GB for 60,000 lines is about 333 kB per line, I don't see how this could happen wih ids as small as you said.

Comment: How did you count the lines?

Comment: You are right, I have updated the quesiton to include a sample. I am counting with the size of the array being written into the file, and later with opening the file with notepad++ and see how many lines it has.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out what was happening. I paused Dropbox, and the symptom seems to have disapeared. I believe that the file being written while Dropbox doing the sync probably was messing with the structure of the file.

If this goes south again I will post it here.